# Having Trouble Storing Cookies from expressjs to the browser

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, session-cookies, httpcookie

i'am trying to store cookies from express js in the browser, they work fine on localhost but not after hoisting them (both frontend and backend are hosted in the same place render.com)

frontend : https://frontend.domain.com

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://backend.domain.com",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export { api };
```

back-end : https://backend.domain.com

cookies.js :

```
exports.options = (maxAge) => {
    // return { domain: process.env.cors_origin, SameSite: "None", secure: true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 }; this not work so i try to remove everything but still not work
    return { httpOnly: false, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 };
}; 

exports.create = (data, CustomMaxAge) => {
    ...
    return { token, defaultValue: exports.options(maxAge) };
};
```

router.js

```
const cookies = require("cookies.js");

const { token, defaultValue } = cookies.create(data, age);
res.cookie("cookie", token, defaultValue);
res.sendStatus(200);
```

server.js

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.cors_origin,
    credentials: true
}));
```

config.env

```
cors_origin=https://frontend.domain.com
```

it's look like i setup everything correctly but i can't find the cookies in the front-end and i can't read them from the back-end, (i don't mean to display the cookies on the frontend but find the cookies in the dev tool)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I can’t see anywhere that you try to read the cookie in your server side code. (Nor the client side code, but that’s impossible anyway).